# Javascript if characters in a string has the same count occurance

Tags: javascript, string, count, character

How to find if all distinct characters in a sting have the same count for example `aassdd` has the same count of `'a', 's' and 'd'`. I know how to compare characters to each other but i don't know where to hold the numbers of each occurance

```
  function letterCount(string, letter, caseSensitive) {
      var count = 0;
      if ( !caseSensitive) {
        string = string.toUpperCase();
        letter = letter.toUpperCase();
      }
      for (var i=0, l=string.length; i<string.length; i += 1) {
        if (string[i] === letter) {
            count += 1;
        }
      }
      return count;
    }
```

My question is  how to hold the number of each character occurance and than to compare them

Comment: I don't want to compare all  the characters to a particular character I want to see if the occurances of each characters are equal

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. Looks like you have a good answer below anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object and the characters as property for count.

```js
function letterCount(string, caseSensitive) {
    var count = {};
    if (!caseSensitive) {
        string = string.toUpperCase();
    }
    for (var i = 0, l = string.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (!count[string[i]]) {
            count[string[i]] = 0;
        }
        count[string[i]]++;
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(letterCount('aAssdD', false));
console.log(letterCount('aAssdD', true));
```

Comment: Why the firtst console log returns false and the second true?

Comment: `true`/`false` is the parameter `caseSensitive` of the function `letterCount`. it is not part of `console.log`.

Comment: Posted 5 minutes ago and the site tells me 5 seconds before I post almost an identical answer.  Thanks SO!  Obviously, this is a good answer though ;)